# Why does service restart after activity is closed in which it was created?

Tags: android, service

I had created a service that scans for the ibeacons and started using an `Activity` on button click. It works well but when I close the activity the service stops and restarts automatically. At the restart time the service cannot detect ibeacon.
I want it to be such that once you start the service it runs all the time.
So please help me.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: you may bind service to activity.

Comment: post your program code

Comment: I dont know how to bind service to activity. Please show me an example     of how to bind service to activity.

Answer (score 0):

Before u going to start a Service check the service is already running or not by using the following code

---

```
/** is service running */
public static boolean isServiceRunning(Context mContext) {

    boolean serviceRunning = false;
    try{
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> l = am.getRunningServices(50);
    Iterator<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> i = l.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo = (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo) i.next();
        if (runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals("com.manikanta.testapp.MyBackgroundService")) {
            serviceRunning = true;
        }
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return serviceRunning;
}
```

com.manikanta.testapp -> package Name.
MyBackgroundService -> this is your service class name

if it returns true service is already running, that time u don't start the service
if it is false start the service

Comment: Guys, I have found what is the problem in the service. After Activity is closed, the service also stops. And in "onStartCommand" I have written the code "return Service.START_STICKY;", beacause of this code service is started again. So please tell me how will be service started at only once and not again stops.